# What I am looking at? Duplicate symbols?

Tags: ios, objective-c, linker-errors, duplicate-symbol

I have these messages on Xcode

```
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_Cars._color in:
    /Users/myUsername/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myApp-ecspkaggqtvfeuglkpunmntelswf/Build/Intermediates/myApp.build/Debug-iphoneos/myApp.build/Objects-normal/armv7/Cars.o
    /Users/myUsername/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myApp-ecspkaggqtvfeuglkpunmntelswf/Build/Intermediates/myApp.build/Debug-iphoneos/myApp.build/Objects-normal/armv7/SpriteSlider.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_Cars._brand in:
    /Users/myUsername/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myApp-ecspkaggqtvfeuglkpunmntelswf/Build/Intermediates/myApp.build/Debug-iphoneos/myApp.build/Objects-normal/armv7/Cars.o
    /Users/myUsername/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myApp-ecspkaggqtvfeuglkpunmntelswf/Build/Intermediates/myApp.build/Debug-iphoneos/myApp.build/Objects-normal/armv7/SpriteSlider.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_Cars._place in:
    /Users/myUsername/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myApp-ecspkaggqtvfeuglkpunmntelswf/Build/Intermediates/myApp.build/Debug-iphoneos/myApp.build/Objects-normal/armv7/Cars.o
    /Users/myUsername/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myApp-ecspkaggqtvfeuglkpunmntelswf/Build/Intermediates/myApp.build/Debug-iphoneos/myApp.build/Objects-normal/armv7/SpriteSlider.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_Cars._state in:
    /Users/myUsername/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myApp-ecspkaggqtvfeuglkpunmntelswf/Build/Intermediates/myApp.build/Debug-iphoneos/myApp.build/Objects-normal/armv7/Cars.o
    /Users/myUsername/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myApp-ecspkaggqtvfeuglkpunmntelswf/Build/Intermediates/myApp.build/Debug-iphoneos/myApp.build/Objects-normal/armv7/SpriteSlider.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_Cars in:
    /Users/myUsername/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myApp-ecspkaggqtvfeuglkpunmntelswf/Build/Intermediates/myApp.build/Debug-iphoneos/myApp.build/Objects-normal/armv7/Cars.o
    /Users/myUsername/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myApp-ecspkaggqtvfeuglkpunmntelswf/Build/Intermediates/myApp.build/Debug-iphoneos/myApp.build/Objects-normal/armv7/SpriteSlider.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Cars in:
    /Users/myUsername/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myApp-ecspkaggqtvfeuglkpunmntelswf/Build/Intermediates/myApp.build/Debug-iphoneos/myApp.build/Objects-normal/armv7/Cars.o
    /Users/myUsername/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myApp-ecspkaggqtvfeuglkpunmntelswf/Build/Intermediates/myApp.build/Debug-iphoneos/myApp.build/Objects-normal/armv7/SpriteSlider.o
ld: 6 duplicate symbols for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

The duplicate symbols it mentions are not duplicate. These are four properties declared in my Cars class like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) void (^color)();
@property (nonatomic, copy) void (^brand)(Cars *oneCar, NSSet *touches);
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *place;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSString *state;
```

The other class SpriteSlider does not have these properties. How can it be duplicate?

How do I discover the problem. Can Xcode give more detailed messages? Thanks

NO, the same classes are not being compiled twice in the build phases.

Comment: How are you importing your Cars class header file into your SpriteSlider .m or .h file?

Comment: It's complaining about the variables, not the properties. It's also complaining about the `Cars` class. Somehow you seem to be creating two `Cars` classes. Double check your `SpriteSlider.h` and `SpriteSlider.m` files.

Comment: Michael, you are a genius. I havetyped #import "Cars.m" by mistake !!!! Please make this comment an answer, so I can accept that!!!!!! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're importing your Cars class .m file into your SpriteSlider.m file by mistake.  Switch it to "`#import "Cars.h"`" and you'll be all set.

And you're welcome!